# While studying compTIA A+ while preparing to enter the field of information security, should I focus on the hardware part?

Tags: security

I am a beginner in the field of information security, I studied networks and I am now studying the compTIA A+ course, I know that I was supposed to take the compTIA A+ course before the networks, but what happened happened, the question now is should I focus on the hardware part while studying the compTIA A+ course or take a quick look at it because I will not come into contact or deal with it in the future and pay more attention to the software part?
i guess i will pentest a software not a hardware at the end of this field